# MySql conditional update TRIGGER giving odd syntax error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, triggers, sql-update

I'm trying to set up a TRIGGER to update some LONGTEXT fields in the `wp_user_favorite_events` table based on what it is updated when the `wp_postmeta` table is update. However, no matter what I do I can't seem to get the query to line up correctly. At this point, it gives me the two errors at the bottom when I try to execute the trigger. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TRIGGER postmeta_UpdateFavorites                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
AFTER UPDATE           
ON wp_postmeta 
FOR EACH ROW        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    IF     OLD.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' 
       AND OLD.meta_value <> NEW.meta_value 
    THEN 
         UPDATE wp_user_favorite_events 
         SET wp_user_favorite_events.event_start = NEW.meta_value 
         WHERE wp_user_favorite_events.post_id = NEW.post_id;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ELSEIF     OLD.meta_key = '_EventEndDate' 
           AND OLD.meta_value <> NEW.meta_value 
    THEN 
         UPDATE wp_user_favorite_events 
         SET wp_user_favorite_events.event_end = NEW.meta_value 
         WHERE wp_user_favorite_events.post_id = NEW.post_id;
    END IF;
END;
```

> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
>
> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSEIF OLD.meta_key = '_EventEndDate' AND OLD.meta_value <> NEW.meta_value THEN     ' at line 1 for query

Comment: I used the same solution as found in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34541/multipart-formatted-mysql-query-problem/34653#34653 It worked perfectly!

Comment: Trigger text itself is correct. [modelling fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27b57d1af9af3c76322f7f0571da14ba).

Comment: The problem was $wpdb can't run multi statement queries. The link in my other comment shows the solution I used.